Construct a function $G=G(x,y)$ of class $\mathcal{C}^1$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $\{(x,y):G(x,y)>0\}=(0,1)\times(0,1)$
Let $\rho$ be a $\mathcal{C}^\infty$ bump function with supp $\rho=[0,1]$
Let's define the functions

Then, let $G(x,y):=f(x,y)h(x,y)$
I believe this function $G$ satisfies the requirements, since it is the product of two $\mathcal{C}^\infty$ functions and is positive exactly in $(0,1)\times(0,1)$
My question is: is there a way to construct a function that meets the requirements WITHOUT using bump functions?

Consider $h(t) = e^{-1/t^2} \mathbf{1}_{{t > 0}}$ which is of class $\mathscr{C}^\infty$ and $h = 0$ for $t < 0.$ Now consider $u(x,y)=h(1-x)h(1+x)h(1-y)h(1+y)$

@WilliamM. I think this function is greater than zero in $(-1,1)\times(-1,1)$, since $1-x,1+x,1-y,1+y$ are all greater than zero in $(-1,1)\times(-1,1)$. I don't know how I would use it to construct $G$

Replace $1+x$ and $1+y$ by $x$ and $y$, respectively.
